# jQuery Datatables aoColumns Sorting error

Tags: jquery, datatables

Ok I am using DataTables from Datatables.net
I have one table that seems to be suffering a sort issue. Currently "aoColumns" is set up like

```
null,
{"iDataSort": 2, "bSortable": true},
{"bVisible": true, "sType": "num"},
{"iDataSort": 4, "bSortable": true},
{"bVisible": true, "sType": "num"}
```

What it is is 5 columns 2 of which are hidden so.. 
0 is the column with the inital sort issue that sparked this post.
1 is supposed to be display purpose only
2 is hidden and is supposed to act as the sort for 1
3 is supposed to be display purpose only
4 is hidden and supposed to act as the sort for 3

I need the first column to recognize as html so it strips out the HTML as it has links in it, currently its set to `null` and the problem with this is it breaks the sorting in Chrome.

I have tried to make it like

```
{"sType": "html", "bSortable": true},
{"iDataSort": 2, "bSortable": true},
{"bVisible": true, "sType": "num"},
{"iDataSort": 4, "bSortable": true},
{"bVisible": true, "sType": "num"}
```

Which breaks the table itself.

First I tried

```
{ "sType": "html", "bSortable": true},
{ "sType": "num", "bSortable": true},
{ "sType": "num", "bSortable": true}
```

(before I realized I had 2 hidden columns) Which this worked but broke the table layout physically. So now Im stuck trying to go from a to b keeping all 5 columns the 3 displayed, and the 2 hidden and failing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
aoColumns: [
   {"sType": "html", "bSortable": true},
   {"iDataSort": 2, "bSortable": true, "bUseRendered":false},
   {"bVisible": true, "sType": "numeric"},
   {"iDataSort": 4, "bSortable": true, "bUseRendered":false},
   {"bVisible": true, "sType": "numeric"}
]
```

I had to do this with a column that rendered images instead of the values and then created a hidden column which had the actual values to sort on.

I hope this helps